# Menu doesn't work in libreoffice 3.6

Tags: unity, libreoffice

**Translated (using Google Translate):** I have a problem with Libreoffice and menu bar. I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 and I find that when I open a libreoffice file does not exit the menu by hovering the title bar. I think it's a bug and reported. Opening a new file and then open the document that comes with it.

I would appreciate it if you solved this problem would tell me how to fix it. Thank you.

---

**Original:**

Tengo un problema con Libreoffice y su barra de menús. Tengo instalada la distribución ubuntu 12.10 y me encuentro que cuando abro un fichero de libreoffice no sale el menú al pasar el ratón por la barra de título. Creo que es un bug ya reportado. Abriendo un fichero nuevo y luego abriendo el documento consigo que salga.

Agradecería que cuando esté solucionado este problema me dijerais como solucionarlo.
Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1064962 (In SRU, in quantal-proposed)
and
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-appmenu/+bug/1075263 (In preparation)